# Within Marklogic, combine two json objects

Tags: json, marklogic

I have two json objects defined. I want these combined to produce the json object shown below.

```
let $a := object-node { "child1" : "one"}
let $b := object-node {"child2" : "two"}
let $s := ???
return ($s)
```

where s is

```
{ "parent" : {
    "child1" : "one",
    "child2" : "two"
} }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $a := object-node { "child1" : "one"}
let $b := object-node {"child2" : "two"}
let $s := object-node {"parent": $a + $b}
return ($s)
```

Comment: JSON Objects are specialized maps, so they can take advantage of Map Operators https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/hashtable#id_71045